# Не получается обработать исключения

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

Требуется вывести дату. Года не должны быть внутри 1900 и 2050. И обязательно ООП.

На вход даётся в форме dd.mm.yyyy:

30.11.2019

На выходе:

day: 30
month: 11
year: 2019

```
import datetime

class Data_:

    def _init_(self, date_):
        self.date_ = date_

    def read_D(self, s):
        self.date_ = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%d.%m.%Y')
        if 1900 > int(self.date_.year) > 2050:
            raise print('Error year')
        return self.date_

    def show_D(self):
        print ('day: {0}\nmonth: {1}\nyear: {2}'.format(self.date_.day, self.date_.month, self.date_.year))

s = input()
d = Data_()

# try:
#     d.read_D(s)
#     d.show_D()
# except 1900 > d.year > 2050:
#     raise print('Error year')

d.read_D(s)
d.show_D()
```

Не удаётся обработать исключения, пробовал и внутри класса, и вне класса (закомментированый скрипт).

Comment: А вы попробуйте создать новый файл.py импортировать ваш класс в файл.И после во втором файле создать обьект класса,и там же его вызывать

Comment: А можете сказать, что будет? Я сейчас несколько ограничен действиях, т.к. не на своем компе и нет IDE, поэтому смогу только вечером.

Comment: Под рукой только онлайн интерпретатор.

Comment: К сожалению не смогу,т.к тоже нету под рукой компьютера.

Comment: с трудом понимаю условие `1900 > int(self.date_.year) > 2050` , может вам надо сделать так: `1900 < int(self.date_.year) < 2050` ?

Comment: Условие простое, Вы написали: период, который находится внутри диапазона. А мне нужно сделать исключение, т.е. если вдруг выпадут не входящие в этот диапазон, то код должен кинуть исключение. Я думаю int необязательно.

Comment: тогда так:  `not 1900 < int(self.date_.year) < 2050`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

class Data_:

    def _init_(self, date_):
        self.date_ = date_

    def read_D(self):
        self.date_ = datetime.datetime.strptime(input(), '%d.%m.%Y')
        if not 1900 < self.date_.year < 2050:
            raise ValueError()
        return self.date_

    def show_D(self):
        print ('day: {0}\nmonth: {1}\nyear: {2}'.format(self.date_.day, self.date_.month, self.date_.year))

def main():
    d = Data_()
    try:
        d.read_D()
    except ValueError:
        raise print('Error year')
    d.show_D()


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if not 1900 < 2 < 2050:
    try:
        raise Exception('An exception flew by!')
    except Exception:
        print('Error year!')

# Error year!
```

---

```
if not 1900 < 3000 < 2050:
    try:
        raise Exception('An exception flew by!')
    except Exception:
        print('Error year!')

# Error year!
```

---

```
if not 1900 < 2019 < 2050:
    try:
        raise Exception('An exception flew by!')
    except Exception:
        print('Error year!')
```

---